# How to create a gdal_retile pyramid from a irregular shaped mosaic?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic, image-pyramids

I'm trying to use  `gdal_retile.py` to create a pyramid and retile the source mosaic of `.goetif` files. The problem is the source files are cut to the shape of a specific property and the first tile created by gdal has the name `name_01_25.tif`. So after retiling the first layer the output is:

```
ERROR 4: /directory/name_01_01.tif: No such file or directory
Error opening: <class 'NameError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_retile.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal_retile.py", line 1081, in main
    buildPyramid(g, minfo, dsCreatedTileIndex, g.TileWidth, g.TileHeight, g.Overlap)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal_retile.py", line 762, in buildPyramid
    levelMosaicInfo = mosaic_info(minfo.filename, inputDS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal_retile.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.bands = fhInputTile.RasterCount
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'
```

Is this a general problem that it always expects a starting tile with the name `01_01.tif` or is there a way to specify the starting tile name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by updating to the latest unstable version `GDAL 3.8.4, released 2024/02/08` The problem got discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/8260) and someone fixed it.